# Calling component methods after redux-saga API call completion: use componentDidUpdate or pass the method to the action creator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm wrestling with converting an existing React project to redux-saga.  I'm learning redux-saga because the team I'm joining asked me to and I thought converting this project would be a good way to learn.

The chief problem I've encountered is that my project was very much promise-based and, particularly within App.js, I could make my API calls and then take various actions based on success or failure.

Using redux-saga I've largely lost this control: unless I use a package like `redux-thunk-saga`, or monitor variables in the store to try to determine if an API call has succeeded, I don't know whether my API calls have succeeded.

In particular, after my user has logged in, I want to set up socketIO listeners.  I have a method in App.js that does this.  But if I run the `authenticate` saga, I don't know whether it has succeeded in order to call my `setupSocketIO` method.

One solution I thought of was to monitor the redux `state` and see if my login  token had changed using `componentDidUpdate`.

Another possible solution would be to pass the `setupSocketIO` method as a parameter to my `authenticate` action creator.  Sort of like this within app.js (in pseudo-code)

```
   /* APP.JS */

    import {authenticate} from actionCreators  
    dispatch(authenticate(name, password, this.setupSocketIO.bind(this))

    setupSocketIO = (name,token) => {
         ... 
    }


/* SAGAS/AUTHENTICATE.JS */

function* authenticate() {
     try {

      const {name,password, setupSocketIO} = yield (actionTypes.AUTHENTICATE)
      const token = call(apiLogin(name,password)
      call(setupSocketIO(name,token)
     } catch (error) {
       ...  
     }
```

so that the authenticate saga `call`s this method if the login is successful.

Which of the two (if either) would be the better approach to allow the component to call its own methods on API call completion?

Comment: Move setupSocketIO to a middleware, and dispatch an action from the saga to start the setup.

Comment: At the moment the method, which contains all the socketIO listeners, is reliant on the App.js component, that is it references other methods in the component through `this`.  How would I (or could I) bind the method to App.js if moving it to the middleware?  (Also, if you have a link to an example or source that illustrates what you're saying, I'd appreciate, as I'm new to redux...)

Comment: Ideally, a view component should only do view stuff. All side effects should go to middlewares (sagas are an example). So if you can break it out of the App, a middleware is a good place for the setup logic. Here is a general example  of socketIO in a middleware - http://nmajor.com/posts/using-socket-io-with-redux-websocket-redux-middleware.